# How to extract values from a table and create a new table

Tags: excel

I am learning how to use Excel and would like to ask a question.

[image]

In the highlighted region, I would like to create a new table called summary and 
I would like to extract the values from the ANOVA Table.

The criteria is that IF the Significance = *, the Summary Table tells me the Source, the value of F and its corresponding p-value.

I am imagining that I can use lookup functions, but if you could lead me to a good source to learn this technique I would really appreciate it.

Edited:

[image]

I tried the code but the values were all A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way would be to use Power Query. Have you ever used it? You can download it for free from Microsoft's site. After install, then follow these steps. Make ANOVA table an actual table by clicking CTRL+T, then bring that table into Power Query, keep columns you want, then filter by 'Significance' column.

If you don't want to go that route. Here is a formulaic solution for you.

Cell O4 (Enter with CTRL+Shift+Enter): `=IF(ROWS(O$4:O4)>COUNTIF($N$3:$N$17,"*"),"",INDEX($H$3:$H$17,SMALL(IF($N$3:$N$17="*",ROW($N$3:$N$17)-ROW($N$3)+1),ROWS(O$4:O4))))`

Cell P4 (Enter with CTRL+Shift+Enter): `=IF(ROWS(O$4:O4)>COUNTIF($N$3:$N$17,"*"),"",INDEX($L$3:$L$17,SMALL(IF($N$3:$N$17="*",ROW($N$3:$N$17)-ROW($N$3)+1),ROWS(O$4:O4))))`

Cell Q4 (Enter with CTRL+Shift+Enter): `=IF(ROWS(O$4:O4)>COUNTIF($N$3:$N$17,"*"),"",INDEX($M$3:$M$17,SMALL(IF($N$3:$N$17="*",ROW($N$3:$N$17)-ROW($N$3)+1),ROWS(O$4:O4))))`

Comment: I feel like I am able to see what you are doing but it did not really work on my end.  Can you explain to me a little more in detail?  I do see that the other two columns work the same way so can you focus on the Cell O4 please?

Comment: Can you please let me know exactly what didn't work? These formulas should provide you with the exact results you are wanting.

Comment: I'm sorry it actually worked this time. . . I must have mistyped or something.  Can you elaborate the big picture, though?
Here are the things that I wold like some explanation.
1), Condition Statement in IF . . . why are we comparing the number of cells in a column vs the number of * ?

2), The Small Statement
It is a bit too complex for me to really know what is going on.  I can see that we want to index something, but how are you finding that particular value?

Comment: These type of formulas are tricky. First off, this is an array formula, hence why you have to enter with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. We are comparing the number of rows because if the formula goes past the number of rows that is greater than the number of *, then we want blank (nothing), else return the values. The small statement is basically saying return the first time it's found (row 1), if the formula is on the second row, then find the second time it is mentioned, and so on so forth... this would be easier if you added a helper column to the right of column H (insert a column in between H and I).

Comment: And then use the below two formulas.

Comment: O3: =COUNTIF($N$3:N3,N3) and P4: =IFERROR(INDEX($H$3:$H$16,MATCH(ROWS(P$4:P4),$O$3:$O$16,0)),"")

Comment: Also, if this helped answer, then please mark this answer as correct. Thank you and please reach out with any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

In cell I4 enter the formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$17,SMALL(IF($H$3:$H$17="*",ROW($H$3:$H$17)-2),ROW(A1))),"")
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. Copy across and change the reference for the Index to `INDEX($F$3:$F$17` and `INDEX($G$3:$G$17` accordingly. Remember to confirm with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Copy down.

[image]

Excel has some new functions that are currently available only to some insider builds with Office 365. With these functions, the command will be a lot easier.

```
I4 =FILTER($B$3:$B$17,$H$3:$H$17="*")
J4 =FILTER($F$3:$F$17,$H$3:$H$17="*")
K4 =FILTER($G$3:$G$17,$H$3:$H$17="*")
```

Copying down is not required. The formula will automatically "spill" into the cells below as required.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I tried your method but it did not work out for me.  I have no idea why.  One question, though.  we know that ROW (A1) = 1 so why did you not just say 1 ?

I have edited my work.

Comment: The reference to A1 will change when the formula is copied down. So, in the next row it will return 2, then 3, etc.

Comment: If you use EXACTLY the same layout and use the first set of formulas and you enter them with CTRL+SHIFT+Enter, then it will work. If it doesn't you have an error somewhere or you did not use Ctrl+Shift+Enter.